# Mathjax offline for web view

Tags: react-native, offline, mathjax

Using webview to render math content by linking mathjax cdn for react native is common. But how to approach the problem of making it offline.

1. Is there a way to locally maintain that bundle?
2. Is it even prefered?
3. What will be the size of the bundle ? I dont want my app size to go beyond 10mb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download your mathjax from

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html

into => android/app/src/main/assets/

Now in your webview html code set script reference to

```
<script src="file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

and your necessary config inside html.
Also make sure to set base url to your folder name.

```
<WebView source={{ html, baseUrl: 'file:///android_asset/MathJax/' }} />
```

Also you can https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-grunt-cleaner to reduce the Mathjax asset size by removing unnecessary fonts and formats that you don't use.

Comment: Its not working for me after using MathJax-grunt-cleaner. any idea?

Comment: you have to make sure you are removing only files that you don't need

Comment: Sorry but I have zero experience with JavaScript, can you guide me about this?

Comment: basically you would have a config set on mathjax script loading location MathJax.Hub.Config. In the grunt file you can disable other configs that you dont need. for example Im using HTML-CSS as output so I don't need commonHtmlOutput, svgOutput, previewHtmlOutput, plainSourceOutput. So comment those out and then run the grunt file. Make sure you don't remove anything that you might need

Comment: @GaudamThiyagarajan how to using for ios in react native? because ios not have android_asset

Comment: in new MathJax download - there's no file MathJax.js in MathJax-master folder