# Mathjax offline for react native

Tags: react-native

I am making an educational application and need to display math formulas in offline. On android I already know how to do this but on the react-native, that way doesn't work. Almost no mathjax support library for native react. Except for this library: [mathjax for react native](https://github.com/calvinkei/react-native-mathjax). And it only supports online. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Shouldn't I install and apply according to the installation manual on the link?

Comment: It is good for online.

Comment: That MathJax library uses a WebView to display the content so there is no possible way for it to be displayed offline

Comment: @Perniferous in Android it working for offline, this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867501/mathjax-offline-for-web-view  , but in ios I can't find assets folder .